# Purchase a product using it's id or displayName

Tags: swiftui, storekit

I've been following a few tutorials online regarding setting up Storekit in my app. I've gotten as far as successfully requesting all the products and holding them in a `products` array. The next step of these tutorials is almost always listing out the products using a `ForEach` like so:

```swift
ForEach(products) { product in
  Button {
    Task.init {
      try await purchaseProduct(product)
    }
  } label: {
    HStack {
      Text(product.displayName)
      Spacer()
      Text(product.displayPrice)
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't work for my use case, unfortunately. The design I'm working off has 3 buttons in different parts of the screen, each of which initiate a purchase request for a different product.

I've managed to get *some of the way there* by doing this:

```
Button {
    Task.init {
        try await purchaseProduct(products.first!)
    }
} label: {
    HStack {
        Text("\(products.first?.displayName ?? "No name")")
        Spacer()
        Text("\(products.first?.displayPrice ?? "No price")")
    }
}
```

But this feels really hacky to me, for the following reasons:

- Force unwrapping doesn't feel correct
- I can make this work for the `.first` and `.last` item in the `products` array **but** I don't know how to get the second item, and this also means if the order of items inside `products` changes, my UI ties the wrong product to their respective button.

Here's my `purchaseProduct` function:

```
func purchaseProduct(_ product: Product) async throws -> StoreKit.Transaction {
    let result = try await product.purchase()

    switch result {
    case .pending:
        throw PurchaseError.pending

    case .success(let verification):
        switch verification {

        case .verified(let transaction):
            await transaction.finish()
            return transaction

        case .unverified:
            throw PurchaseError.failed
        }
    case .userCancelled:
        throw PurchaseError.cancelled

    @unknown default:
        assertionFailure("Unexpected result")
        throw PurchaseError.failed
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
if let productOne = products.PRODUCTID {
  Button {
      Task.init {
          try await purchaseProduct(productOne)
      }
  } label: {
      HStack {
          Text("\(productOne.displayName)")
          Spacer()
          Text("\(productOne.displayPrice)")
      }
  }
}
```

But I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to get there.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/first(where:)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand how to apply this (or even which part of my question its solving). Would it help me use a product id, the displayName of just the number in the array?

Comment: You said that you want to do the equivalent of `if let productOne = products.PRODUCTID` -- my suggestion is to use `first(where:)` to find the item you want in the `products` array.

Comment: Ok. I've tried `if let productOne = products.first(where: { $0 == "iap.myapp.ProductOne"}) { button...}` and it's saying `Referencing operator function '==' on 'StringProtocol' requires that 'Product' conform to 'StringProtocol'`

Comment: You're trying to compare a `Product` to a `String`. Instead, you should do something like `{ $0.id == "iap.myapp.ProductOne" }`

Comment: `if let productOne = products.first(where: {$0.id == "iap.myapp.ProductOne"}){ Text("\(productOne.displayName)") }` worked, thank you so much. Could you write a reply so I can give you the answer credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired `if let productOne = products.PRODUCTID`, you can use `first(where:)`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/first(where:)

```
if let productOne = products.first(where: {$0.id == "iap.myapp.ProductOne"}) {
 // ...
}
```